# How can i add image when i want to respone page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I want write simple web application to wirite any data with asp.net respone and show that line a simple image,i create image dynamically with this code:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Width = 50;
myImage.Height = 50;
myImage.ImageUrl = "direction_arrow_green_down.png";
this.Controls.Add(myImage);
```

and write simple respone with this code:

```
 Response.Write("<br/>"+ "SAMPLE");
```

but i want write this:

```
Response.Write("<br/>"+ "SAMPLE"+myImage);
```

i want somthing this:
[image]

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: You need to create `HttpHandler`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why you cant try like this ?

```
 string img = "<img src='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-web-navigation/165/tick-128.png' width='128' height='128'>";
        Response.Write("<br/>" + "SAMPLE" + img); ;
```

Comment: its my pleasure @behzadrazzaqi